# Histogram of signal with a time shift added

Tags: matlab, histogram

One of the problems in Proakis's signal processing book using Matlab asks to plot the histogram of

```
x3(n) = x1(n) + x1(n-1)
```

where `x1(n)` is a random sequence.

To create `x1(n)`, I do the following:

```
n1 = 1:100000;
a = 0; b = 2; % interval over which to pick random numbers.
x1 = a + (b-a)*rand(100000,1);
N1 = hist(x1,100);
figure, bar(N1);
```

To generate x3(n), I use a couple of helper-functions defined in Proakis's book.

```
[x31,n31] = sigshift(x1,n1,1);
[x3,n3] = sigadd(x1,n1,x31,n31);
N3 = hist(x3,nbins);
figure, bar(N3);
```

Unfortunately, I do not have enough points to post images. However, the histogram of the random sequence `x1(n)` just shows that `x1` is uniformly distributed. The `x3(n)` however, looks more like a Gaussian distribution.

I don't understand why this happens, and would appreciate if someone could explain this a bit.

Thanks.

Comment: I've found a simple explanation. The probability density function for the sum of two dice looks like a triangle. When we add two random sequences where one has been shifted, we basically throw two dice. That explains the distribution of x3.

Comment: Users are encouraged on Stack exchange sites to answer their own questions if they are able to come up with a solution on their own, so you might consider fleshing this out to an actual answer instead of just a comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, $x_3[n]$ is the sum of two [iid random variables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independent_and_identically_distributed_random_variables), $x_1[n]$ and $x_1[n-1]$. Since each is taken from the [uniform distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_distribution_%28continuous%29), the [probability density function (pdf)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function) of each is:

$$
f_{x_1}(x) = \begin{cases}
\frac{1}{b-a}, & x \in [a,b] \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

This is just a [rectangle function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rectangle_function) that is scaled and shifted to lie on the interval $[a,b]$. One property of the sum of independent random variables is that the pdf of the sum is equal to the convolution of the individual random variables' pdfs. Therefore:

$$
f_{x_3}(x) = f_{x_1}(x) * f_{x_1}(x)
$$

If you convolve two rectangles together, you get a [triangle function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_function). Therefore, if you histogram enough samples of $x_3[n]$, you should see the plot converge to a triangular shape.

Comment: Add enough uniformly distributed RV's together, and you'll eventually get to the [CLT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Central_limit_theorem)!

Comment: Much appreciated!